# ASPNET Core MVC build failed without any error showing

Tags: .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having problem in razor view. I am creating multiple forms iteratively. This creates the forms perfectly except when I try to assign the created form an `id`. The `id` value comes from the model object. Since `id` value must not contain spaces I tried to remove it using `string.Replace` function but after this vs build fails with no error.  I also tried creating a variable and use it but it still do not build. There are no errors from visual studio it only says build failed.

Here is my markup and code:

```
<div class="card-body">
@{
    var distinct = Model.DistinctBy(m => m.CategoryName).ToList();

    @for (int i = 0; i < distinct.Count(); i++)
    {
        <p>@distinc[i].CategoryName</p>

        <form id="@distinc[i].CategoryName.Replace(' ', '')" asp-route-PatientVisitId="Model.CurrentVisit.PatientVisitId" asp-action="Diagnosis" asp-controller="opd">
        @{
            var items = Model.Where(m => m.CategoryName == distinc[i].CategoryName).ToList();
        }
        <div class="row g-3">
            @for (int k = 0; k < items.Count(); k++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4 pt-0 pb-0 mb-0 mt-0">
                    <label class="form-label">@items[k].ServiceName</label>
                    <input asp-for="@items[k].Result" class="form-control form-control-sm" />
                </div>
            }
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    }
}
</div>
```

I tried creating variable - got no change

```
string formId = distinc[i].CategoryName.Replace(' ', '');
<form id="@formId"
```

If I remove `Replace(' ', '')` it builds successfully.

```
<form id="@distinc[i].CategoryName"
```

My questions:

- Why does the build fail / what is the error?
- What should I do to fix it?

Comment: For the future, you can change verbosity of the dotnet build command to see more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the character literal to string literal
Replace

```
<form id="@distinc[i].CategoryName.Replace(' ', '')"
```

With

```
<form id="@distinc[i].CategoryName.Replace(" ", string.Empty);"
```

I figured it out after adding `FormId` property in the model class and assign it in the `constructor` as follows

```
public ReportModel()
{
    this.FormId = this.CategoryName.Replace(' ', '');
}
```

and vs automatically complained about the issue saying
`CS1011: Empty character literal` [Compiler Error CS1011](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1011?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS1011)) which it doesn't in razor file. Thank you.